# What is the formula for determining time dilation (as the object in motion)?

Tags: special-relativity, time

The formula for calculating how much time passes for a still observer is T=TO/(1-v^2/c^2)^1/2.  How do I calculate what TO is?

Comment: $$\Delta t' = \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$
In natural units, where $t^{'}$ is the time observed by a stationary object, and $t$ is the time as measured by the object in motion.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for time dilation is

$$\Delta t =\frac{\Delta t_{0}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}=\Delta t_{0}\gamma$$

Where $\Delta t$ is the time that passes for the moving observer (according to the  stationary observer), $\Delta t_{0}$ is the time that passes for the *stationary* observer, $v$ is the relative velocity between the two observers.

There is also length contraction:

$$ l =l_{0}\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}=\frac{l_{0}}{\gamma}$$

Where $l$ is the objects length according the stationary observer and $l_{0}$ is the original length (or length of object according to moving observer). There is also relativistic energy

$$E=\gamma mc^2$$

Where this expression accounts for both rest mass energy and kinetic energy. The factor $\gamma$ can be anything from 1 to infinity (when $v=c$).